# In a database with 4 connected tables, how can I insert data into one table and cascade the data onto the other 3?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables: dogs, owners, breed, and owners_dogs.

Each table has their own primary key id, with owners_dogs being the junction table.

Now I want to INSERT INTO dogs, 1 owner, and simultaneously his 2 dogs into dogs table.
Furthermore, I want to insert 2 more owners to owner table, owning 1 seperate dog each.

I see that inserting into the owners table wont update the junction table, nor the dog table.

Do I simply add an owner_id into the junction table first, for then to use the same id when inserting into the owner_table?

Answer (score 0):

This is problematic because you can't specify values for the other columns that belong to the `owners` table.

That is, I assume the `owners` table has columns for the owner name, email, and probably other attributes. But if you `INSERT INTO dogs` or even if you `INSERT INTO owners_dogs`, you can only specify values for the columns of those tables.

You could write a trigger to insert a row to the `owners` table, but you would have to rely on default values or something. Then you could `UPDATE owners` to set the other attributes. But if you have to do a second SQL statement to fill the other attributes anyway, then why not do that as an `INSERT INTO owners` *before* you reference it in subsequent inserts?